# What is the difference between Compare() and CompareTo() for strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string, compare, compareto

I know it returns integer but I needed to know on what basis.

**Example:**

```
string s1 = "world";
string s2 = "World";

Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(s1,s2));   

Console.WriteLine(s1.CompareTo(s2));
```

it returns `-1` for both. But if we *capitalize* `w` in `s1` and lowercase w in `s2` it returns `1`.

So need some explanation for it.

Comment: Besides that one is static (and can handle therefore the null case for s1 better) while the other is not they do identical things. Presumably internally CompareTo calls Compare.

Comment: For your question about the result. Compare does a "greater as","smaller as", "equal" comparison.  So if you exchange values the result changes with it if they aren't equal.

Comment: @Ralf it will check for length of the string as well?

Comment: What about their [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-7.0) is unclear to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see the *difference* when one (or both strings) is `null`:

```
string s1 = null;
string s2 = "World";

// -1, since null < "World"
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(s1,s2));   

// NullReferenceException thrown, attempt to call null.CompareTo("World")
Console.WriteLine(s1.CompareTo(s2));
```

Comment: this clarifies my doubt

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about behaviour then they are the same and both under the hood call same `static int string.Compare` with defaulted `StringComparison.CurrentCulture`.

The main difference lies in `static method` vs `instance method`. So `s1.CompareTo(s2)` throw `NullReferenceException` if s1 is null.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, both the **Compare()** and **CompareTo()** methods are used for string comparisons, but they have different implementations and return types.

1. **Compare()** Method:

- The **Compare()** method is a static method of the **string** class in C#. It
  compares two strings and returns an integer that indicates their
  relative order in terms of sorting.
- The return value of **Compare()** is an integer less than 0 if the first
  string is less than the second, 0 if they are equal, or an integer
  greater than 0 if the first string is greater than the second.
- It allows you to perform case-sensitive or case-insensitive
  comparisons based on the specified **StringComparison** enumeration
  value.
- The **Compare()** method can be useful for sorting and ordering
  operations.

Example usage of **Compare()**:

```
string string1 = "apple";
string string2 = "banana";
int result = string.Compare(string1, string2);
```

2. **CompareTo()** Method:

- The **CompareTo()** method is an instance method of the **string** class in
  C#.
- It compares the current string instance with another string and
  returns an integer that indicates their relative order in terms of
  sorting.
- The return value of **CompareTo()** is similar to Compare(): less than 0
  if the current string is less than the other, 0 if they are equal, or
  greater than 0 if the current string is greater.
- It performs a case-sensitive comparison by default but can be used
  with the **StringComparison** enumeration to specify case-insensitive
  comparisons.
- The **CompareTo()** method is typically used for natural sorting or when
  comparing strings in an object-oriented manner.

Example usage of CompareTo():

```
string string1 = "apple";
string string2 = "banana";
int result = string1.CompareTo(string2);
```

Both **Compare()** and CompareTo() can be used to compare strings, but **Compare()** is a static method that accepts two string parameters, while CompareTo() is an instance method called on a single string instance.